# Searching CIL based on date of the texts origin

Tags: corpus-inscriptionum-latinarum

For a project of mine, I would like to gather inscriptions from a certain period from CIL. The books however are sorted based on area where they were found. Is there some list sorted by date (I understand that this might not be an exact date, but might just be something like from the 4th century A.D.)? I found one website, [Epigraphik-Datenbank  Clauss / Slaby](http://db.edcs.eu/epigr/epi.php), which seemed to do such a thing, but when one just searches on blank terms, it seems to return more queries than there are in CIL, so I am not sure whether this website is that reliable.

Comment: Enter CIL in the "publication" field to limit the search to CIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy - see the screenshot below how to do it on http://db.edcs.eu/epigr/epi.php?s_sprache=en (EDCS):

[image]